# HttpResponseRedirect in Django is not redirecting to the page views.py file

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, response.redirect

My views.py looks like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django import forms


from . import util
import markdown2


def index(request):
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
        "entries": util.list_entries()
    })


def entry(request, title):
    if title not in util.list_entries():
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {
            "error": "Page Not Found",
            "query": title
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", {
            "entry": markdown2.markdown(util.get_entry(title)),
            "title": title
        })


def search(request):
    if request.POST["q"] in util.list_entries():
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("entry", args=(request.POST["q"],)))
    else:
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html")
```

Here my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:title>", views.entry, name="entry"),
    path("search", views.search, name="search")
]
```

Next comes my layout.html template which other pages extend from this:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="{% static 'encyclopedia/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
                <h2>Wiki</h2>
                <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="POST">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
                </form>
                <div>
                    <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    Create New Page
                </div>
                <div>
                    Random Page
                </div>
                {% block nav %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
            <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
                {% block body %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

What I need here is redirecting a user to the entry page if the search matches the query (if it matches with my entry). My entry function in views.py is working fine (which renders entry.html if the title matches), but the search function is not redirecting to the entry page. What is the right way in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

```
if request.POST["q"] in util.list_entries():
```

This line will only match if the search string matches an entry exactly.

You could loop through the entries, and check whether the entry contains the search string. For example:

```
for entry in util.list_entries():
    if request.POST["q"] in entry:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("entry", args=(entry,)))
```

Comment: Alasdair, yeah, your version is good. But it is not working in my function too. Something should be changed here

Comment: My answer was missing the `()` in `util.list_entries()` before.

Comment: If that doesn't work, then I can't really help debug - I don't know what result or error you are getting, or what `util.list_entries()` returns. Try adding lots of print statements to your code (e.g. `print(util.list_entries)`, `print(request.POST["q"])`, `print(entry)`, `print(request.POST["q"] in entry)`. That should help you work out where your code is working differently than you expect.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to use 'redirect'
To import `redirect`:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
```

It may work.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. The problem was in urls.py file of my app. There was a collision of paths.